# Multiple class selector not working

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, background-image

I've searched up and down trying to find a fix for this and so far nothing has worked. I have a section element with a class and it repeats on the main pages of a site. Only difference is the background image changes. I can't get the background image to show up though. After tinkering around a bit it seems like I can't get my selectors to be recognized at all.

Here's an example:

HTML for box on home page

```
<section class="maincontent"></section>
```

HTML for box on portfolio page

```
<section class="maincontent port"></section>
```

CSS

```css
.maincontent {
width: 860px;
height: 540px;
margin: 50px;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.maincontent.port {
background: url(../images/portduck.jpg) no-repeat top;
}
```

I've tried using an ID of #port instead of multiple classes, tried putting a space between .maincontent and .port, tried changing the order of classes, nothing has fixed it. I also experimented with trying to override the width and height of the box and nothing happened which makes me think it's my selector that's the problem or something to do with box-shadow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably doesn't have anything to do with your selector.

Comment: Possible cause - an error in your CSS before the desired rule that stops other rules from working.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping out. After checking through everything suggested I found the culprit. Our freelance web designer forgot to put an ending curly bracket on her CSS for some keyframe animations!

Answer (score 2):

1- Make sure the image path is correct (hover over the URL in developer tools, etc, or check the network panel).

2- Try adding display: block to the CSS for that class.

Comment: Unless you're using an HTML5-compliant browser, or shim (polyfill) for HTML5, the section element will be rendered inline, not block.

Answer (score 1):

If you give a selector of ".maincontent .port" (note the space between), than to match this you must have a tag with a class of "maincontent", and nested inside that you must have a tag with a class of "port", like

```
<div class="maincontent">
  <p class="port">
  ... whatever ...
  </p>
</div>
```

If you want a single tag to get the properties of two classes, make the classes unrelated, and then give both class names separated by a space.

```
CSS:
.maincontent {... whatever ...}
.port {... whatever ...}

HTML:
<div class="maincontent port">
```

I'm not sure what happens when you give both a background-color and a backgroun image. If they're clashing, one easy thing to do would be to break the background-color into another class, and then invoke the appropirate combinations. Another option is to add "!important" to the background image. This tells the system to give it a higher priority. Also, the general rule is that longer chains of specifiers take priority over shorter chains, so ".maincontent .port" should win over anything that is just in ".maincontent".

Answer (score 1):

your css for `.maincontent.port` is overriding the background-color, and setting it to the default (transparent). If you want to inherit the black background color from `.maincontent` you need to do this:

```
.maincontent.port {
    background-image: url(../images/portduck.jpg)
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```